# Large array inside a nested namespace c++

Tags: c++

I would like to know if there is a difference in behavior if I create an array inside a namespace vs outside a namespace eg

```
//file.hpp
static char array[512];
```

vs

```
namespace a::b::c
{
static char array[512];
}
```

It seems when I use `snprintf` with an array that is inside a namespace I get unexpected behavior.

Essentially this fails to work correctly:

```
uint8_t write_byte(char byte)
{
    snprintf(array, 8, "%d", byte);
    return 0;
}
```

Some other information is that if I go into GDB, and I print the address of array, it gives me an address of another variable.

Comment: unexpected behavior? What did you expect, what happened instead? Please post a [mcve]

Comment: There is no difference, from the compiler's perspective, aside from the obvious namespacing rules. There must be something else you're doing in your code that makes them different. Remember, if *any* part of your code exhibits undefined behavior, then that can cascade into other parts of your program and produce odd effects.

Comment: what is the meaning of "fails to work correctly"? The link I provided above explains how to create a mre. Please provide one, otherwise we can only guess what your issue is

Comment: "*Essentially this fails to work correctly*"" - well, for starters, `char` may be signed, ad so if `byte` is a negative value then 4 is potentially too small for the buffer size and thus `array` may be truncated. You would need 5 instead, since the smallest negative `char` value is `-127`, which is 5 `char`s including the null terminator.

Comment: isnt `%d` for signed integers? Though that would not make a difference for different `array`

Comment: Try `snprintf(a::b::c::array, 8, "%d", static_cast<int>(byte));`

Comment: "*I would like to know if there is a difference in behavior if I create an array inside a namespace vs outside a namespace*" - there is no difference, as far as this code is concerned. "*if I go into GDB, and I print the address of `array`, it gives me an address of another variable*" - that makes sense, as you are declaring a `static` variable in a header file. If you `#include` that header in multiple translation units, each unit will get its own copy of the variable. If you want to share a single variable across units, use `extern` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the [`printf` family](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) have a very specific syntax. If you turn your compiler warnings up, most modern compilers will warn you if you violate it. In particular, `%d` is the indicator for an integer. You've given it a character. `snprintf` uses the old C-style varargs syntax, which means it can't validate types at compile time. Therefore, your code is trying to interpret a `char` as an `int`, ends up (on most sane architectures) reading random memory, and exhibits undefined behavior. The compiler is free to do as it pleases.

Based on the link above, `%hhd` is the signifier for a character, or you can explicitly cast `byte` to `int` before passing it to `snprintf`.

Comment: "*snprintf uses the old C-style varargs syntax, which means it can't validate types at compile time*" - modern C++ compilers can validate the arguments of printf-family functions at compile-time. Some compilers (ie, gcc) also have extensions to validate user-defined printf-style functions, too.